# How to make hair strands go a specific direction without using particle edit

Tags: particles

I have a strip of hairs, and I want those particles to go towards the right side and a bit random waviness, and also make the particles thicker. I tried using particle edit, but its slowing my PC system for some reason, and the particles are only 500. And I also trying to make the particles a random thickness using hair shape, but its not working.

[image]